# Loop to get values from DataGridView1 getting stuck on last row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am looping through a datagrid view trying to extract values. I wanted to start with the value in **column one**, *instead* of column zero.

In the following code..

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col--)
    {
        string dataGridValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridValue);
        if (col == 0)
        {
            col = col + 2;
            if (rows < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count) {
                rows = rows + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                rows = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It just keeps getting the last row of the dataGridView. Obviously I am doing something wrong with the row counts. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's one confusing code...

Comment: this is a weird loop.  I imagine a lot of your problem is from comparing rows to columns `if (rows < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count)`, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Modifying your loop variables (rows and col) inside your loop is not the best of ideas.

Comment: If I am doing it wrong (trying to read the full DataGridView, starting from column one) can someone show me how it is supposed to be written?

Comment: The inner most if statement was checking to make sure the value wasn't going out of the bounds of the array (-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
// -1 because you want to start at column 1
var extractedValues = new object[dataGridView1.RowCount, dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1];  
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.RowCount; row++)
{
  for (int col = 1; col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; col++)
  {
    extractedValues[row, col -1] = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value;
  }
}
```